# Reading ppm file and coverting to greyscale or inverted

Tags: c++, vector, fstream, ppm

I can't seem to get the file to be read, I want the user to input the name of the file, say "wallpaper", and then I convert it to the filename "wallpaper.ppm". I want to take this input, convert the numbers into vectors, and then either convert the file to greyscale or invert it depending on user input. thanks

```
// A5.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    struct Pixel {
        int Red;
        int Green;
        int Blue;
    };
    vector <vector< Pixel> > image;
    string fileType;
    int height{}, width{}, maxColor{};
    string p3;
    cout << "Enter the name of the file:";
    cin >> fileType;
    string fileTypeActual = fileType + ".ppm";
    ifstream myImage(fileTypeActual);
    if (myImage.fail()) {
        cerr << "Fail";
        return 1;
    }
    while (!myImage.eof()) {
        string p3;
        myImage >> p3 >> width >> height >> maxColor;
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            vector<Pixel>rowofPixels;
            for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                Pixel p;
                myImage >> p.Red;
                myImage >> p.Green;
                myImage >> p.Blue;
                rowofPixels.push_back(p);
            }
            image.push_back(rowofPixels);
        }
    };
        myImage.close();
        int userChoice;
        cout << "Would you like to invert the colors or convert to greyscale? Type 1 for greyscale and 2 for color inversion";
            cin >> userChoice;
            if (userChoice == 1) {
                //begin greyscale conversion
                string fileGray;
                fileGray = fileType + "_grayscale.ppm";
                ofstream imageOut(fileGray);
                if (imageOut.fail()) {
                    cerr << "Fail";
                    return 1;
                }

                struct greyPixel {
                    double redGrey;
                    double blueGrey;
                    double greenGrey;
                };
                vector <vector< greyPixel > > greyScale;
                //gray = 0.2989 * Red + 0.5870 * Green + 0.1140 * Blue
                for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
                    vector<greyPixel>rowofGrey;
                    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                        int pixelRed = ((image.at(i)).at(j)).Red;
                        int pixelBlue = ((image.at(i)).at(j)).Blue;
                        int pixelGreen = ((image.at(i)).at(j)).Green;
                        greyPixel g;
                        g.redGrey = 0.2989 * pixelRed + 0.5870 * pixelGreen + 0.1140 * pixelBlue;
                        g.blueGrey = 0.2989 * pixelRed + 0.5870 * pixelGreen + 0.1140 * pixelBlue;
                        g.greenGrey = 0.2989 * pixelRed + 0.5870 * pixelGreen + 0.1140 * pixelBlue;
                        rowofGrey.push_back(g);
                    }
                    greyScale.push_back(rowofGrey);
                }
                imageOut.close();
            }
            else if (userChoice == 2) {
                //begin color inverson 
                string fileInvert;
                fileInvert = fileType + "_inverted.ppm";
                ofstream imageInv(fileInvert);
                if (imageInv.fail()) {
                    cerr << "Fail";
                    return 1;
                }
                struct invertPixel {
                    int redInvert;
                    int blueInvert;
                    int greenInvert;
                };
                vector <vector< invertPixel > > invert;
                for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
                    vector<invertPixel>rowofInvert;
                    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                        int pixelRed = ((image.at(i)).at(j)).Red;
                        int pixelBlue = ((image.at(i)).at(j)).Blue;
                        int pixelGreen = ((image.at(i)).at(j)).Green;
                        invertPixel inv;
                        inv.blueInvert = maxColor - pixelBlue;
                        inv.greenInvert = maxColor - pixelGreen;
                        inv.redInvert = maxColor - pixelRed;
                        rowofInvert.push_back(inv);
                    }
                    invert.push_back(rowofInvert);
                }
                imageInv.close();
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Can you reduce the code example to the part that actually gives you the error? It's called a [Minimal Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and will make it easier for us to help you.

Are you saying that opening the file is giving you an error or is it happening downstream?

Comment: hey simon thanks for your reply. I cant open the file, the code runs without error, and returns 1, indicating to me that it runs to completion. the issue i am expecting is that i am not opening the file  and reading it correctly

Comment: where is the input file present?

Comment: While you say "the code runs *without* error, and returns **1**", the posted code has a couple of `if (/*..*/.fail()) { cerr << "Fail"; return 1; }`. Is there any `Fail` in the output?

Comment: What Bob__ said. But also: Put a breakpoint on the line ```ifstream myImage(fileTypeActual)```, step through the code and try to find out what actually happens. Which ```return 1``` statement is actually encountered?

Comment: hey so the fail is from opening the file.

Comment: Is the file in the same location as the executable? Are you providing the full path or just the file name?